# MachineKeys folder permission CryptographicException Windows 10

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-10, file-permissions

My application uses RSACryptoServiceProvider and I have had problems on two (out of more than a thousand) customer's computers.

The issue is quite simple and easy to fix, but requires human interaction and I'd like to avoid it.

The issue is that I get a CryptographicException calling RSACryptoServiceProvider's constructor. It happens because the user cannot write in his RSA MachineKeys folder ( C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys ), even tho the user has admin rights on his computer (UAC stuff?).
Pretty easy to fix, just add the user to MachineKeys and give him write permission.

Both computer on which it happened were on Windows 10 (coincidence or not, i don't know).
It seems to be somewhat common on Windows 10 and manifests itself in different ways. For example, people report they cannot join Home Groups from their Windows 10 computers for the same reason and the fix is the same.

So first, why does this happens ? I've read that it may be caused by the folder being created by another user, but even then, i don't understand why it doesn't get created with proper permissions.

Second, is there a way to fix it in such a way that it is transparent to my users ? I could verify if I have write permissions in the directory, but then, I doubt I can't change permissions programmatically...

Thanks in advance :)